# Best way to pass an array from JavaScript to C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web-services

I need to pass an array from JavaScript to a page method in C#. I have tried using a parameter in the C# method of IList and also a string[] array. Both ways throw an exception "cannot convert an object of type system.string to xxx", where xxx is the parameter type in the C# method. I am passing the object from jQuery as a json object, and looks like it is coming through properly. Here is what it looks like:

```
{"testNumbers":"5555555555,3333333333,4444444444"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: C# Code:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void ProcessAction(string[] testNumbers)
{
    var dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    dataProvider.ProcessAction(testNumbers);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, two things:

1. JSON arrays have square brackets around them
2. JSON numbers aren't quoted.

Try this instead:

```
{"testNumbers": [5555555555,3333333333,4444444444]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one of the .NET JSON Deserializers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
{"testNumbers":["5555555555","3333333333","4444444444"]}
```

should i think do the trick along with a deserialiser. see [`http://www.json.org/`](http://www.json.org/) which has a great graphical representation of the json syntax.